# The concept of split Access database and using OleDb with it

Tags: database, ms-access, split, oledb

I've run into problems with Access database as it's maximum size is limited to 2 GB. I've done a little research and found about split Access databases. When splitting the database, the original file remains and one new is added. I don't quite understand what I'll be getting with this. As I understand, the newly created file is a back-end - the data is stored here, the original file is just a front-end with forms, queries, etc. The limit on back-end file will still remain effective. Am I right? Perhaps multiple splits will do the trick, but I don't understand the concept of it.

If multiple split is possible and I would be able to store more than 2 GB in virtually single database, how do I do it with OleDb. More specifically, am I supposed to interact with front-end database only, and Access will distribute the data by itself? I'm familiar with OleDb, just not sure about this whole split concept.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you have more than 2GBs of data you need a different data store than Jet/ACE. I would say that if you have 1GB now, you already need a different data store. There is no non-kludge way to get around this limitation, and mucking about with the various kludges is just a waste of time and you'll ultimately have to move to a different database engine anyway as soon as one of your component back ends hits the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

re: *The limit on back-end file will still remain effective. Am I right?*
yes

Basically, you move all your table objects to one or more other databases and link to them in the front-end db with your forms, queries, etc.

One problem with splitting dbs is enforcing referential integrity.  You can only do that within one .mdb file.

If you really need everyone to have access to massive amounts of data, consider storing it on SQL Server or some other back end instead.

Comment: I wish I had a choice, I'd use SQLite instead. Thank you very much for your answer. Can you explain anything about OleDb connection?

Comment: with OleDB, you pass a connection string to one or more .mdb files.  If you split into multiple .mdb files, you just need to manage more connections for different tables in your schema.